# Communicate from Android device to iPhone using hotspot and local http server?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, http, hotspot

Is it possible to run an HTTP server on my iPhone ([CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)) and then connect to the iPhone hotspot from an Android device? I am thinking I would find the IP address of the hotspot (somehow) and then communicate directly to the iPhone HTTP server over the hotspot connection.

Or to put it another way: Is there anyway to communicate (app to app) from Android to iPhone without any other hardware/networks involved?

Note: No Bluetooth BLE on Android device.
FYI: iOS 7 and Android 4.0.4

Comment: mDNS / zeroconf / "Bonjour"?

Comment: @Charles, thanks, but have you ever tried this? Seems crazy that in 2013 we can't get Android an iPhone to communicate directly.

Comment: Ok, got something working. Running CocoaHTTPServer on iPhone (iPhoneHTTPServer sample app with setPort 12345), and then connecting to iPhone hotspot on Android and using android browser to go to 172.20.10.1:12345 retrieves the web page from the iphone. Sadly though, Jmdns on Android does not detect the service and therefore I have no idea if that IP address (172.20.10.1) will always be used by the hotspot or not. Seems to be the default though.

Comment: Also I don't really know for sure if I'm completely bypassing cell towers, but I suspect so. Android has cell data off, iPhone needs it on otherwise hotspot does not stay on. iPhone wi-fi is not connected to anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm neither an iOS nor Android dev, so I probably won't be any additional help here...